# Irreducible components of scheme over the 2-adic integers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are the $2$-adic integers. What are (the coordinate rings of) the irreducible components of $X$?

Here is what I've tried so far: The "Chinese Remainder Theorem map"
$$\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x-1\rangle\times \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x+1\rangle$$ is injective, but not surjective because $\langle x-1\rangle + \langle x+1\rangle=\langle x-1,2\rangle\neq \langle 1\rangle$. I think that the image of the map contains
$$(2\mathbb{Z}_2[x]+\langle x-1\rangle,2\mathbb{Z}_2[x]+\langle x+1\rangle),$$ but this is obviously not the whole image since the identity must also be there.